# Java (and MySQL) backend, jQuery Frontend, trying to use Jersey-few questions

Tags: java, php, jquery, mysql, tomcat

Java (and MySQL) backend, jQuery Frontend, trying to use Jersey.

My java backend stores the key information I want to display in MySQL, but I also want to send a GET request (to get info) to the UI.

(I'm a beginner, at designing stage)

Questions:

1) I have installed Apache TomCat as my server. Where would I save my directory so i can view it when I try to access it from URL: (localhost:8080..etc.) 
 2) I plan on getting JSON strings from mySQL database; 
    for example, lets say I have a 3 columns; date, name, url. Should I just parse the avaialbe rows into json and display it from there? If so is this how I should approach it:

```
///java side
public class ServerJersey {
    //gets UI input 
    @GET
    @Path("/{info}")
    public Response getInfo(Info info) {
        store_info_to_db(info);
        String reply = "Sent Request!"
        return Response.status(200).entity(reply).build();
    } 

    @POST
    public Info postInfo() {
        Info info = get_info_frm_db()
        return info;
    }
}

//Jquery ---just pseudocode..don't know if its right
$.getJSON(PATH,
    function(storeInfo){
        $.each(info.date, function(i,info.date){
        $("#infolist").append("<li>"+info.date+"</li>");
        });
        $.each(info.name, function(i,info.name){
        $("#infolist").append("<li>"+info.name+"</li>");
        });
        $.each(info.url, function(i,info.url){
        $("#infolist").append("<li>"+info.url+"</li>");
        });
    });
```

3) I plan on letting the user upload a file which is sent to the backend. How do i approach this? (Prefer to use just texteditor and no IDE's (eclipse etc.))

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm new with this so if there are other approaches please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. It varies by your TOMCAT installation folder, I prefer to use the [Tomcat Manager](http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/tomcat/tomcat-manager) application to deploy my webapps.
2. No, because it's not legal code. And it looks like a strange mix of PHP and Java. I would use Jackson or GSON to serialize POJOs.
3. [MIME multipart encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) form-data is how web browsers (not text editors) upload files to a web server (with an input type='file').

   <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" accept="image/png,applicaton/ms-excel">
   </form>